# How can I support drywall with a steel post on an outside corner?

Tags: drywall, basement, framing, structural

I have a steel support post right on the corner of a wall, which protrudes on one wall about 1/4". I am getting ready to look at drywall and wondering is there any other option than to build around this post?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of the new and important information mentioned in the comment below,  your best move is to fur out the entire wall just enough to clear the post. You may then want to follow the advice I gave originally.

---

Original answer:

You can work with that and avoid any sort of bumpout. Just cut a triangular "stud" as large as possible that fits in the available space. Set your circular or table saw to 45 degrees and cut a few sample blocks. Use a straightedge across each wall plane to see what you have room for. You could even hang drywall on one face and then install the stud with screws through the drywall before you add construction adhesive to all contact points.

Ideally you anchor it top and bottom, and even a gob of construction adhesive against the post flanges will do. Even better if you can glue to the drywall and the post itself. As a system it'll be rock solid. Let the adhesive set up for a day before nailing on your corner bead.

If you're wrapping that beam with drywall, install a strip of half inch plywood or OSB under the beam, between the flanges at each end, to get the drywall below the flange and bolt heads.

Comment: The steel post stick out about 1/4" past the stud on the right side. Also the main beam has duct work along side it. So it will be framed around to make the top easier to work with.

Comment: What about making a decorative bump out (simulated column) to cover the real column? Seems like it would be easier than furring out the entire wall and also would be a visible indication of some special structure at that point.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be easier. You'd now have four additional corners (two outside, two inside) to drywall, tape, and trim, not to mention flooring. Sure, it might be a nice design element, but it's in no way easier. You could fur out that wall in about ten minutes.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a picture, but I did a basement for a customer, that couldn't move a wall, to hide a pole like this. I framed out as close as I could to the pole, and used a combination of tear-away bead and "J" bead, to tie the pole into the wall. The pole looks like it belongs there...

[image: j-bead]
[image: tear-away]